# How to save the return value of cd?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this:

```
cd $dir

if[ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...
else echo "The directory doesn't exist"; exit -1;
fi
```

And what I want is that if the cd returns an error (on the 1st line) the error won't be shown by the shell. I only want to be shown the message that I wrote. 
I tried to do:

```
ret=$(cd $dir)
```

But that doesn't work.  How can I do it?

Comment: The `$(...)` syntax captures the *output* of the command, not its status.

Comment: Actually, you do not want to print your message.  You really would prefer that cd emit the error message.  The error may not be that the directory doesn't exist, in which case your error message is incorrect.  Just write: cd $dir || exit -1. (Or just do set -e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect standard error:

```
cd $dir 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: It would be helpful, to me at least, if the reason for the downvote was provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
if cd $dir 2> /dev/null; then ...; else echo "The directory doesn't exist"; exit -1; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

If the directory does exist, but the script does not have permission to enter it, then what you are trying to do is confuse the user.  If your intent is to confuse the user, then go ahead and use the other answers provided.  But what you really want to do is let cd emit the error message and just write:

```
cd $dir || exit 255
```

Trying to print an error message when you have absolutely no idea what error occurred just leads to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd $dir 2>/dev/null || { echo "The directory doesn't exist"; exit -1; }
...
```